# Coloring terminal commands ("syntax highligting" on command line)

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, colors

I do know I can color my prompt using escape sequences in the `PS1` variable.

Now, I would like to know if there is a way to put some color on the `bash` commands I often use, on the command line itself.

I'd like to type something like `ls /home`, and the command `ls` shows in green as I type it, or something like that.

Is it possible?

Comment: Apparently ZSH and fish have support for something like this: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting

Comment: I never seen like this with bash, but you can color any command output with grc and alternatives.

Comment: Related, on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/304211/is-there-any-way-to-get-bash-to-have-syntax-highlighting-like-fish